# How to add new attribute to an existing LDAP user objects

Tags: ldap, openldap

I want to add mail attribute to the existing ldap users. I think, its possible with using ldapmodify but not sure how. I have done that using phpldapadmin web GUI manually, but I have like more than 100 users and dont want to do that manually for all.

Can anyone please guide me in right direction.

Comment: Use Apache Directory Studio for a visual editing experience.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$ ldapmodify -H ldap://yourhost -D cn=youradmin,dc=your,dc=domain -x -W
( enter password here )
dn: uid=username,ou=people,dc=your,dc=domain
changetype: modify
add: mail
mail: youremailaddress@here.com
```

Answer (score 4):

First, I'm going to point you to [Section B.4](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_directory_server/10/html/administration_guide/ldap_data_interchange_format-specifying_directory_entries_using_ldif) of the [Red Hat Directory Server Administration Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_directory_server/10/html/administration_guide/index) for a quick tutorial on how to create [LDIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDIF) files suitable to use with ldapmodify. Create entries for just a couple of your hundred users for a start. This file will help you get the bugs out. Once you're comfortable with the file format, you can create entries for the remaining 100-or-so people. Here's an example of how an individual entry might look:

```
dn: cn=Joe Smith,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: mail
mail: Joe.Smith@example.com
```

The legal values for `changetype:` are `add`, `modify`, `delete`, and `modrdn`. If you use `changetype: modify`, the legal modifications are `add:`, `delete:`, and `replace:`. Section 3.3 will give you examples of how all of those work.

Then, once you have the file written, you have a couple ways to submit it to your LDAP server. One method is to feed the file directly to the [`ldapmodify`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ldapmodify) command:

```
ldapmodify -x -h $LDAP_HOST -D $LDAP_BINDDN -W -f $FILE
```

The `-W` switch tells `ldapmodify` to ask for the password for `$LDAP_BINDDN` at the command line. This means you're not leaving the password to your LDAP server in your shell history file. If you do want to incorporate the password into your `ldapmodify` command, use `-w $PASSWORD`, instead. The `-f $FILE` switch tells `ldapmodify` which LDIF file to examine for the changes being implemented.

I don't actually like using the `-f $FILE` switch. Passing a file to `ldapmodify` requires 100% confidence that I've correctly written that LDIF file. If I make a mistake, `ldapmodify` will exit without telling me my error. So, I would use a second method. Use the `ldapmodify` command I gave as an example, but without that `-f $FILE` switch. Without that switch, `ldapmodify` gets its modifications from [`STDIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STDIN#Standard_input_.28stdin.29). So, I can copy two or three entries from this LDIF file I assembled, and paste them into my shell for `ldapmodify` to process. I do 2 - 4 entries at a time, and make corrections to the LDIF entries on the fly as I need to. This is slower than passing a perfect LDIF file directly to `ldapmodify`, but faster than figuring out where I made a typo in that file.

Comment: I can use your method but I dont want to use the file to save the entries then do the operation. I was looking for a single command so that I can simply write a script using loop to do it.

Comment: You can turn the process I mentioned above into a `bash` script.

Comment: Version 10 of the RedHat docs are not available anymore. Here is a relevant section I found in the v12  docs: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_directory_server/12/html/managing_directory_attributes_and_values/assembly_managing-directory-entries-using-the-command-line_managing-directory-attributes-and-values

Answer (score 2):

For editing LDAP entries directly I prefer to use "ldapvi" which gives you an editor where you can make your changes in a more user-friendly way.

See http://www.lichteblau.com/ldapvi/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `ldapmodify` for this. You need to generate LDIF files which contains the change statements and then direct these to your LDAP server with `ldapmodify`. For more informations, please read `man ldapmodify`, which also contains examples.