# add new attribute to ldap users and submit to ldap

Tags: ldap

its similar to this question [How to add new attribute to an existing LDAP user objects](https://serverfault.com/questions/455621/how-to-add-new-attribute-to-an-existing-ldap-user-objects)
but I don't know how to submit it to ldap. After my attribute I still have got an empty row. 
How can I save the changes to the ldap and finisch the ldapmodify command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `ldapmodify` and typing the LDIF in you need to finish with a blank line for it to be submitted:

```
$ ldapmodify -H ldapi:/// -Y EXTERNAL
dn: uid=alice,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: mail
mail: alice@example.com

modifying entry "uid=alice,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com"
```

Once you see the `modifying entry` line it's safe to Ctrl+C or Ctrl+D.

Comment: Thanks. It says my attribute type is undefined. Which type can I give my key attribute? Is key; long defined?